# No autogenerated xml file on layout folder and src

Tags: java, android, xml

Hello I know this is a really simple question to ask but out of my curiosity, by the way I am just starting learning android programming today, I am wondering why is that in my newly created android application project there are no auto generated activity_main.xml on my
res->layout folder and in the src folder it is empty unlike in this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_hello_world_example.htm) that I followed there are auto generated files afterwards creating the android application. Provided is the screenshot of my project:

[image]

Comment: I suppose you have upgraded your SDK (or made a fresh IDE installation). Do a Help/Check for Updates.

Comment: Yes I just installed it now on my computer. Okay thanks for your suggestion I'll try this.

Comment: Accept all licences and proceed

Comment: It most likely has something to do with the IDE (Eclipse?) version that you are using. Could you give some more information about that?

Comment: @Vyger okay its currently updating now. :)

Comment: @Daan van Hulst Okay I get it now the version is 4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7

Comment: @Vyger okay it says no updates were found. o.O

Comment: Seems like you are using eclipse classic, where you have to install the SDK and ADT manually. I recommend using the ADT bundle which includes everything: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=sk

Comment: @Daan van Hulst Okay I'll try this thanks for suggesting. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday after updating the latest packages on the Android SDK Manager. Fixed it by updating the Eclipse plugin: Eclipse --> Help --> Install new software --> Pasted URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ pressed Enter. After updating the plugin. I created a test project and the Main activity and menu was created by default as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem. No autogenerated xml file on layout folder and src.
Deleted ADK and created afresh from Zip Bundle file adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030.zip
opened Eclipse and it was working - XML and src content looked good.
closed Eclipse and opened sdk manager (using "run as administrator") and did upgrades to default packages.
opened Eclipse, created new Android Application - No autogenerated xml file on layout folder and src.
admittedly I only added the paths for SDK;SDK\tools;sdk\project-tools;sdk\build-tools at this stage to the paths file.
I guess I'll delete again and try this now and download updates again.